# How to get all the subfolders name within a ROOT Folder and create HTML Content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, directory, subdirectory

I am working on a school project and I have to do a static digital menu website for a bar. Because it's static, I used JavaScript where necessary. Anyways, I divided everything into groups, each group is represented by a card with an image and a button. Here is an example:

[image]

This is the source code for a card:

```
<body>

<div id="cards">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="/Resources/Food.png" class="card_image">
        <a href="javascript:showMenu()" class="button">
          <p>FOOD</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

As you can see, in order to add a single card, I had to manually write the whole structure of a card in the second div, with the class="card".
BUT, I must create it dynamically based on the structure of the subfolders inside the Root folder witch is called Resources, here's a scheme:[image]

In order to achieve this I started using JavaScript since it's the only possible way I think:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function showMenu()
    {
        var content = `
        <div class="card">
            <img src="/Resources/Food.png" class="card_image">
            <a href="javascript:showMenu()" class="button">
            <p>FOOD</p>
            </a>
        </div>`;
        document.querySelector("#cards").innerHTML = content;
    }

</script>
```

So, now that I've expressed what I need to do is this: in the JavaScript code you can see that the card was generated manually anyways but I need the content to generate based on the folder structure I have stored locally. In other words, the whole script should take in input the name/path of the ROOT folder which is called "Resources" and from there it should generate the groups based on it's content. For example, if I click the button on the FOOD Card, then it should delete the FOOD and DRINKS Cards and only add the Vegetables Card in this case...I know it sounds complicated but at the end of the day the problem lies in getting the subfolder names, and since the image has the same name of the subfolder, apply it on the `<img>` tag and also on the button. All this, using JavaScript. If you know that some other language would work much better I'm open to suggestions, but I built the entire website until now only using JavaScript.
Anyways, I tried to express the problem the best I could so if something is unclear, I can easily modify the post if needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: JavaScript can't access local file system.

Comment: @Teemu even if all the folders are going to be on the server? What language would work better or how can I approach this in a better way?

Comment: JavaScript (running in a browser) can't access filesystem of a server either. You need to access the filesystem on your server, and then send the filesystem content to a client as a data structure.

Comment: This is a job for an application server. You can google "application server" for more

Comment: @Teemu yes, but once the client clicks on a button, can't I(the server) receive the request and send the new HTML content that is going to be replaced on the client side?

Comment: Yes, that's the way you do it. But it provides server-side programming to build the response, a server can't filter the files and folders on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the image data into a JSON object, then bind related processing functions according to the requirement.